# Solve issue with Matlab 2018b version

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I was very successfully solving an equation numerically in Matlab R2014a with the following code

```
syms a T
v2=-2.3750
g=1;
b=0.0001;
e2=0.5;
k=0.2;
w=-2*cos(k);
eqn = sin(3*k+a)./sin(2*k+a)==v2-w+(g.*T.^2)+(e2.*T.^2.*sin(k)^2)./(sin(2*k+a)^2+b*T.^2*sin(k).^2);
sol = solve(eqn,a,[0 pi]);
digits(5)
solutions = vpa(subs(sol),3);
xx=subs(real(solutions),T,[0:0.1:3])
```

Then I switched to Matlab 2018b and this code fails to give the solutions. I have to restrict `a` to the range $0$ to $\pi$ and $T$ is a vector `T=[0:0.1:3]`. It would give 6 solutions i.e., `xx` will be $6\times 31$. Could someone tell me why the same working code in R2014a doesn't work in R2018b and any possible workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Your code produces error messages under MATLAB 2018b. Do you have a code which works in MATLAB 2018b? Note that stackoverflow is probably a better forum for your question.

Comment: @CarlChristian This code used to work perfectly in R2014a, but perhaps due to some changes in the version R2018b, the solve function returns errors now. That said, it gives an output if we remove `[0 pi]` from the sol. i.e., replace `sol=solve(eqn,a,[0 pi])` by `sol = solve(eqn,a)`. But then I don't know how to implement the constraint on `a`. Secondly, the solution then looks very strange with a bunch of `angle` , `root`, `z` etc. It should be six solutions, i.e., `xx` should be $6\times 31$ instead of $1\times 31$.

Comment: I am now getting the largest dump of warnings from MATLAB that I have seen in a while! In your position I would define a function $f$ of multiple variables, use this function to define a function $g$ of a single variable, i.e., $a$ and then feed this function to fzero. I have confidence in the algorithm used by fzero.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks. Could you send a simple hint or link so I could try to implement this prescription?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) and finally [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html)

Comment: This isn’t a direct response, but rather a change that happened between R2014a and R2018b. It is now default for MATLAB to expand singleton dimensions in binary operations to reduce the need for bsxfun. I don’t know if that is the situation here, but it *may* be having an impact. There were also a significant number of changes—mostly to graphics—in R2014b, which might also be a part of the cause here.

Comment: @Daryl Thanks for your comment. So do you think having a version earlier than R2014a, e.g., R2013b, R2013a and earlier would help avoid this issue? Do you know exactly which version the specific change happened?